# crash (iOs16) when present VNDocumentCameraViewController

Tags: swift, fatal-error, backtrace, vndocumentcameraviewcontroller

With iOS 16, I have fatal error when I launch VNDocumentCameraViewController
(iPad or iPhone)
On my project, with older operating system (like iOS 14, iOS 15) I haven't got this error.
info.plist --> NSCameraUsageDescription is present with description

```
let myScanViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
myScanViewController.delegate = self
self.present(myScanViewController, animated: false)
```

I's happen just after self.present and I haven't got the camera screen.
I do not know where to check and where to add a breakpoint

debug message :
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

I check the backtraces but any idea about the problem.
thank you for your help.

```
0   CoreFoundation                     0x18add6248 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1841a3a68 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                     0x18af7a6d4 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
3   CoreFoundation                     0x18af77a74 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithCapacity:].cold.1 + 0
4   CoreFoundation                   0x18add1828 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 252
5   CoreFoundation                   0x18add2b1c +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 40
6   UIKitCore                              0x18d387f5c +[UIImageSymbolConfiguration configurationWithHierarchicalColor:] + 124
7   UIKitCore                              0x18d7ffd60 -[_UIImageCUIVectorGlyphContent _automaticSymbolConfiguration] + 104
8   UIKitCore                              0x18cff6434 -[UIImageView _symbolConfigurationForImage:] + 72
9   UIKitCore                              0x18cfc77cc -[UIImageView _resolvedImageFromImage:forTrait:] + 96
10  UIKitCore                              0x18cf941fc -[UIImageView _resolvedImageFromImage:] + 152
11  UIKitCore                              0x18cf92d5c -[UIButtonLegacyVisualProvider intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 132
12  UIKitCore                              0x18cf92cb4 -[UIButton _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 52
13  UIKitCore                              0x18cfcd04c -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) intrinsicContentSize] + 120
14  UIKitCore                              0x18cfcd598 -[UIButton intrinsicContentSize] + 148
15  UIKitCore                              0x18cfccbe0 -[UIView _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 52
16  UIKitCore                              0x18cfb74a8 -[UIView _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 244
17  UIKitCore                              0x18d04b4a4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateSystemConstraints] + 88
18  UIKitCore                              0x18d0c9700 -[UIButton updateConstraints] + 72
19  UIKitCore                              0x18d04b378 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 348
20  UIKitCore                              0x18d04b110 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 764
21  UIKitCore                              0x18d04b02c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 536
22  UIKitCore                              0x18d04b02c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 536
23  UIKitCore                              0x18d04b02c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 536
24  CoreAutoLayout                         0x1a72a7e90 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 84
25  UIKitCore                              0x18d04ae08 __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 104
26  UIKitCore                              0x18cfed6e8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 96
27  UIKitCore                              0x18cfed350 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 172
28  UIKitCore                              0x18cfecf50 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 388
29  UIKitCore                              0x18d02cdec -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1064
30  DocumentCamera                         0x1edf3c6c4 -[ICDocCamViewController initializeUserInterface] + 656
31  DocumentCamera                         0x1edf3baa4 -[ICDocCamViewController viewDidLoad] + 1044
32  UIKitCore                              0x18d2dd330 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 84
33  UIKitCore                              0x18cf750a8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 712
34  UIKitCore                              0x18d23c1bc -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 124
35  UIKitCore                              0x18d1025ec -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 196
36  UIKitCore                              0x18d101aa4 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 608
37  UIKitCore                              0x18d1010f4 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 96
38  UIKitCore                              0x18d101058 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 172
39  UIKitCore                              0x18cf5ecec -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1980
40  QuartzCore                             0x18c43b4e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 500
41  QuartzCore                             0x18c44eb9c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 148
42  QuartzCore                             0x18c460098 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 456
43  QuartzCore                             0x18c4973c4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 652
44  QuartzCore                             0x18c47e408 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 88
45  CoreFoundation                         0x18ae5e070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
46  CoreFoundation                         0x18ade6690 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 532
47  CoreFoundation                         0x18ae47f8c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
48  CoreFoundation                         0x18ae4d1e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
49  GraphicsServices                       0x1c3c6d368 GSEventRunModal + 164
50  UIKitCore                              0x18d2fcd88 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
51  UIKitCore                              0x18d2fc9ec UIApplicationMain + 340
52  digitrame                              0x1019c8d88 main + 64
53  dyld                                   0x1a9171948 start + 2504
```

Comment: The error message says you are trying to insert `nil` into an array. `_NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]`

Comment: yes, I see, but in which array ? and why only this error when I call VNDocumentCameraViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

After deconstruct all the projet....the package SumUp (install via pod) is causing the crash....the backtraces is really not explicit about this fatal error !!!!